# Scraping Historical Data Table using VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to scrape Historical Data Table from Yahoo finance using VBA. However I only managed to get only 1 data instead of the whole table. Is there is any easy method to do it? Please help me.

```
Public Sub History()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable '<== Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
      
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0166.KL/history?p=0166.KL", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Pstart(10px)")(0).innerText
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns only the first element of the Element object. This means `...(0).innerText`.

Please, try the next code:

```
Public Sub History()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable '<== Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim hist As Object, el As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, startCel As Range, boolDiv As Boolean
    
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
      
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0166.KL/history?p=0166.KL", False
        .send
        html.Body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set hist = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Pstart(10px)")
    i = 2: j = 2
    Set startCel = ActiveSheet.cells(1, 2)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each el In hist
        If j <= 7 Then
            ActiveSheet.cells(i, j).Value = el.innerText: j = j + 1
        Else
            If InStr(el.innerText, "Dividend") > 0 Then boolDiv = True
            j = 2: i = i + 1
            ActiveSheet.cells(i, j).Value = el.innerText
            If boolDiv Then
                boolDiv = False: j = 2: i = i + 1
            Else: j = j + 1: End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Art76: Did you find some time to test the above code?

Comment: I've test your code, however it gives the data in 1 column. I've modified your code inorder to make the data into 7 column and 40 rows accordingly, but its not working.

Comment: <pre> Public Sub Reply()

    Set hist = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Pstart(10px)")
    
    
    
    For Each El In hist
    
         For i = 1 To 40
       
 
            For j = 1 To 7
      
             ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = El.innerText
        
            Next
        Next
    Next
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub<code>

Comment: @Art76: I did not look to the page you were trying to extract something. I only observed that you deal with the first element of the object and tried iterate between the object elements. I will try adapting the code to arrange the scrapped elements as in the page.

Comment: FaneDuru - it works excellently as I plan....Thank you very much

Comment: @Art76:  Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, vote the answer code up and more important tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...